# LWC lightning-map get current position of center

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, google-map, lightning-map

Im using lightning-map to show account positions. This map has filters to show/hide different types of accounts, that means that the marker list will get updated everytime a filter is changed. The org im working in has many Account records, like 7000+, that means every time a new marker list is loaded it can take up to +7 seconds to load all of them.

The solution I tought of is to load them around the area the user is looking at every 5-10 Seconds or when the user's position has changed enough. But I can't seem to find a way to get the position the user is looking at in the map. Any ideas?

```html
<lightning-map
   center={center}
   zoom-level="13"
></lightning-map>
```

```js
@track center = { location: { Latitude: '51.509865', Longitude: '-0.118092'}}
connectedCallback(){
    setInterval(this.getUserPosition.bind(this),5000);
}

getUserPosition(){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.center));
}

//Console output (While moving map around and stopping every now and then too):
//{"location":{"Latitude":"51.509865","Longitude":"-0.118092"}}
//{"location":{"Latitude":"51.509865","Longitude":"-0.118092"}}
//{"location":{"Latitude":"51.509865","Longitude":"-0.118092"}}
//{"location":{"Latitude":"51.509865","Longitude":"-0.118092"}}
//{"location":{"Latitude":"51.509865","Longitude":"-0.118092"}}
```

I've tried to remove @track from center or add @api to it but it doesn't seem to change anything.